# How to turn off Bluetooth when the paired device not there in area limits in android

Tags: android

For one of my application I need to switch off the Bluetooth when my phone moved from the area limit of paired device, I mean there'll be only one paired device once that is not there in limits I need to turn off Bluetooth automatically.

```
private void setUpConnection() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Connect to a particular Bluetooth device
            mBluetoothDevice = mBluetoothAdapter
                    .getRemoteDevice("00:12:06:04:90:72");
            // mBluetoothDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice("");
            try {
                mBluetoothSocket = mBluetoothDevice
                        .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                mBluetoothSocket.connect();
                //flag = 1;

                //listen to blue-tooth: Read
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                BluetoothSocketListener bsl = new BluetoothSocketListener(
                        mBluetoothSocket, handler);
                Thread messageListener = new Thread(bsl);
                messageListener.start();

                //read json data - remote content
                getJsonData();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Power On Bluetooth Device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to turn off an active Bluetooth

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) 
{
    mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i did this but i need to turn of only when the device is moved away from area limits of its paired device.

Comment: sorry but right now I am in office, and personal emails are not allowed here :(